# proving equation of an invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

as far as i can tell the following sentence is true but what are the steps to actually prove it?

```
If A is Invertable matrix, and AX=B, then every Y!=X will have AY != B.
```

by logic it seems this sentence is true, but how can I prove it? what are the steps of a proof?

Comment: What happens if the opposite is true? If There is an $Y \neq X$, such that $AY = B$?

Comment: @NemisL. If i'd go by this approach i'd try to prove it as follows:
if there is an Y != X such that AY=B. and from the sentence we know that AX=B, which means AY = AX. we can duplicate from left with (-A) and we will get (-A)AY = (-A)AX by Associative property we get => (-AA)Y = (-AA)X which means IX = IY and that means X=Y.

What do you say about this proof? is that enough, is it how I should have been proving it?

Comment: Exactly: By using the assumption that $A$ is invertible, you produce a contradiction: the conclusion $X = Y$ contradicts that $X \neq Y$. So you have proved that the negation of your proposition is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $$AX=B=AY,$$then $$A(X-Y)=0.$$ Now multiply by $A^{-1}$ and conclude.

Comment: I tried to solve it in a reply of my question but it looks like this one is also a way to solve it? or that my solution wasnt enough? anyway If I use your guidelines I'd continue to solve it as follows: A(X-Y)=0 --> (-A)A(X-Y) = 0 --> by Associative property we get --> (-AA)(X-Y)=0 so that I(X-Y)=0. so X-Y=0 which means X=Y.. is that correct? was that the way you tried to show me ?